# App stuck on Splash screen react-native-navigation

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-navigation

I changes the `AppDelegate.m` file according the example on react-native-navigation. I changed the `index.ios` to `index` because react native don't generate `index.ios` file any more.

`jsCodeLocation =[[RCTBundleURLProvidersharedSettings]jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import "RCCManager.h"
#import <React/RCTRootView.h>

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;
#ifdef DEBUG
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
#else
  jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
  [[RCCManager sharedInstance] initBridgeWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation launchOptions:launchOptions];
  return YES;
}
@end
```

Now the app is stuck on splash screen which display project name and below Powered by react native.

```
function onPressLearnMore() {

  Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
    screen: {
      screen: 'app.screens.HomeScreen', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
      title: 'Welcome', // title of the screen as appears in the nav bar (optional)
      navigatorStyle: {}, // override the navigator style for the screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional)
      navigatorButtons: {} // override the nav buttons for the screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
    },
    passProps: {}, // simple serializable object that will pass as props to all top screens (optional)
    animationType: 'slide-down' // optional, add transition animation to root change: 'none', 'slide-down', 'fade'
  });
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

Environment

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.49.3
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to start the app from a handler.
You're right in `RN 0.49` there is a single entry point, so you should call `startSingleScreenApp` from your `index.js`, so your index should look similar to this:

```
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';
import {registerScreens} from './screens';

registerScreens();
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
screen: {
  screen: 'app.screens.HomeScreen', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
  title: 'Welcome', // title of the screen as appears in the nav bar (optional)
  navigatorStyle: {}, // override the navigator style for the screen, see "Styling the navigator" below (optional)
  navigatorButtons: {} // override the nav buttons for the screen, see "Adding buttons to the navigator" below (optional)
},
passProps: {}, // simple serializable object that will pass as props to all top screens (optional)
animationType: 'slide-down' // optional, add transition animation to root change: 'none', 'slide-down', 'fade'});
```